# Wagtail ImageChooserPanel giving a error `no such column: projects_projectblogdetail.project_image_id`

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I currently got an issue when trying to use ImageChooserPanel in wagtail. My goal is to make a blog type model that will accept a header image. My issue is I keep getting a error saying that no column exists called project_image_id.

Error:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: projects_projectblogdetail.project_image_id`

Do I need to add the project_image_id by itself? Or is that suppose to be taken care by the ForeignKey?

Here is my model code:

```
class ProjectBlogDetail(Page):
    """
    The Our Projects page will work as a blog to add new project articles
    """
    template = "projects/blog-detail.html"

    project_body = RichTextField(blank=True, default="Project Description")

    project_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+'
    )

    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('project_body'),
        ImageChooserPanel('project_image'),
    ]

    def serve(self, request):
        context = news_letter_subscribe_form(request)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            newsletter_form = NewsletterForm(request.POST)
            if newsletter_form.is_valid():
                return news_letter_subscribe_form_submit(request)
        else:
            context.update({
                'post': self,
            })
            return render(request, 'projects/blog-detail.html', context)
```

Any help will be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Did you run `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate` after adding the ForeignKey?

Comment: Yeap. I have done it a couple times. Even deleted the migrations files except the .init and still no luck

Comment: Alright I have no idea what was wrong. I deleted my migrations file again, but renamed the .sql file also to double check that. And now it works so it must have been something in the DB that was causing the issue.